# Android BackupAgentHelper Implementation Not Working

Tags: android, android-backup-service

I have read so many different unresolved questions on this topic and struggled with this for a couple of days now.

I have implemented the BackupAgentHelper class to allow my application to backup.

- I have included the API key in my Android manifest obtained by registering.
- I have declared my BackupAgentHelper in the application tag of the Android Manifest.
- I have implemented a SharedPreferencesBackupHelper and a FileBackupHelper in my BackupAgentHelper to backup a sharedpreferences file as well as a database.

Now according to the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) that is all I need to do implement a backup solution. Great. So now onto testing. I have tried many different tests.

1. Followed the test spec in the Android docs. Queue package for backup, run backup, uninstall app, reinstall app and even force restored.
2. Queue package for backup, run backup, clear app data, force restore.
3. Queue package for backup, run backup, factory reset device, reinstalled app, force restored.

Goes without saying none of these restored my data.

Has anyone else had issues but resolved them with this? It is a feature that should be easy but just not working!

Comment: i have exactly the same problem. did u got a solution in the meantime?

Comment: I'm afraid not. After searching online it seems that not many people could get this working. We are going to use our own sync system instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Manifest file to see if under application you have android:allowBackup="true" as well as android:backupAgent having the correct path to your projects FileBackupAgent. Also, your meta-data should have your registered key, such as android:value="your-registerd-key"

Make sure your device is connected to a Wi-Fi network. Also, make sure in your device Settings, the Backup and Reset needs to have "Back up my data" checked, and "Backup account" has a valid gmail account, and "Automatic restore" is checked.

In addition, in a command window, your transport settings should be: *com.google.android.backup/.BackupTransportService

You can see this by typing: bmgr list transports If transport is set to local, then enter: bmgr transport com.google.android.backup/.BackupTransportService

Other bmgr commands to use to "kick" start your backup in https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard are:

```
 bmgr enabled 
 bmgr wipe "your package in your manifest file"
 bmgr backup "your package in your manifest file"
 bmgr run
```

Refresh your https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard to see the latest backup timestamp